# BackgroundWorker ignoring foreach iteration

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, backgroundworker, nullreferenceexception

It's a continue of

I've narrow down the problems and now when I'm running on debug mode I can see that for some reason not all the `Foreach` iterations are completed, I have a debug every iteration, when the program stops I can see that I'm iterating on a 4 items list, but the loop is executed only 3 times which causing the program to throw a `NullrefrenceException` - because not all objects has been created.

This is my Loop

```
foreach (var system in allSystems.ToList())
{
    Debug.WriteLine("inside Foreach in system: " + system.Name + " interface " + system.Interfaces.Count + " structs " + system.Structs.Count);
    if (nodes == null)
        Debug.WriteLine("Node is Null");
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Before add node");
            lock (networkLocker)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("trying to add: " + system.Name + " " + system.InputNum + " " + system.OutputNum + " " + system.Interfaces.Count + " " + system.Enums.Count + " " + system.Structs.Count);

                nodes.Add(CreateNode(system.Name, new Point(width, height), false, system.InputNum, system.OutputNum, system.Interfaces, system.Enums, system.Structs, update));
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Success adding new node to list");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.addMessage("Error in adding new node to list " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("Error in adding new node to list " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

    width += 150;
    if (width >= 700)
    {
        width = 0;
        height += 100;
    }
}
```

The allSystems contains 4 elemnts (I can see that on debug) but the `Debug.WriteLine("inside Foreach in system: " + system.Name + " interface " + system.Interfaces.Count + " structs " + system.Structs.Count);` is only printed 3 times, and the list `nodes` contains indeed only 3 elements.

Any thoughts?

So to explain what i'm expiriancing i added 2 pictures from the debugger:

this is the list that i'm iterating on:

[image: List of 4]

this is the nodes list that should add node every iteration:

[image: nodesList]

Comment: Why do you check for `nodes == null` but still call `nodes.Add` even if it's `true`?

Comment: Are you sure that the 4th element is not actually a `null` value?

Comment: for debugging, it's not supposed to be null in that point, if it is null it shouldn't come there anyway

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt nope, i can see all the data inside the list that i'm iterating on, but for some unreasonable reason it iterates only 3 times

Comment: I'm so going to use `Debug.WriteLine("FUUUCCKKKK!");` in my future projects. *ahem* More seriously: why are you `lock`-ing the `.Add` ? It doesn't seem multi-threaded **unless** `CreateNode` is: in that case, you have a sever design issue IMHO. Side note: you can probably remove the `.ToList()` from the `foreach` statement

Comment: @Alex yeh lol it's one of the best, cause if this happens i'm really fu*ked lol,
The create node is sending the created node to the backgroundWorker progress to add it to the main list in the main thread, that is why i have a lock on the add

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Debug.WriteLine("inside ...")` throws an exception, cause either `system.Interfaces` or `system.Structs` is `null`.

You should go within VS to `Debug - Exception` and enable all types of exception to find the one that throws the exception. To make it easier to enable or disable all exceptions at once you should maybe take a look at the [Exception Breaker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de), who simply puts this behaviour into one button.

Comment: On debug i see that they are not null, they have all the values in them. when i'm running on Ctrl+f5 it works on and off, but if i'm just pressing f5 always the same exception that is caused by the skipped `Foreach` loop